# create custom meta box with default value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I am creating a custom admin panel where the admin can choose between 3 layout using radio buttons. Everything works perfectly except when admin creates a new page there isn't default option.

I solved this by using:

```
if ($layout == "") {
  $layout = "layout_1";
}
```

I hope someone can help me with a better solution to set up default value for the newly created pages meta

Here is the full code:

```
function page_layout_metabox(){
    add_meta_box( 'page_layout_selector', 'Page Settings', 'page_layout_selector', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function page_layout_selector(){
$layout = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'layout', true);
//set default
if ($layout == "") {
  $layout = "layout_1";
}
?>
<div id="page_layout_container">
  <p id="page_layout_title">Page layout</p>
  <div class="radio_container">
    <div class="form">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="layout" id="layout_1" value="layout_1" <?php if ($layout == "layout_1" ) echo "checked";?>>
        <div class="radio" id="layout_1">
          <span class="icon-on"></span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="layout" id="layout_2" value="layout_2" <?php if ($layout == "layout_2" ) echo "checked";?>>
        <div class="radio" id="layout_2">
          <span class="icon-on"></span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="layout" id="layout_3" value="layout_3" <?php if ($layout == "layout_3" ) echo "checked";?>>
        <div class="radio" id="layout_3">
          <span class="icon-on"></span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea. It seems everything is right. But I would prefer-

```
if (empty($layout)) {
  $layout = "layout_1";
}
```

instead of this-

```
if ($layout == "") {
  $layout = "layout_1";
}
```

It's the preferred method to test if the variable is empty or not. And I would also prefer-

```
if ($layout === "layout_1" ) echo "checked"
if ($layout === "layout_2" ) echo "checked"
if ($layout === "layout_3" ) echo "checked"
```

Instead of this-

```
if ($layout == "layout_1" ) echo "checked"
if ($layout == "layout_2" ) echo "checked"
if ($layout == "layout_3" ) echo "checked"
```

Otherwise it seems quite normal. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement in the code I will update it as you described!

Comment: Well if this answer helped you, would you please accept the answer ? It would be great. @iwan